# February 2023 Writing Challenge: Killing for a cause

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

As decided by vote, here's the next challenge, proposed by [Selina](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/56573/selina):

> Write a scene where the protagonist is forced to hurt or kill a friend/someone they are close to, to achieve a purpose. (For example, to further a cause or movement, or maybe even save someone else.)

---

Go onward and write! Then post your story here as an answer, and get feedback in the comments. If you [ask a main site question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) while writing for this challenge, leave a comment below this question or mention it in your answer.

Follow this question if you want to be notified instantly of any new answers.

You can also post and vote on future challenges here: [The next writing challenge could be yours](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/34330)

Comment: Very yucky is all I can say.

Answer (score 1):

He raised his killing instrument, and dark liquid pooled at the tip like blood. His heart rushed. Ecstasy. Terror. He trembled out a long breath.

There was no scream, no protestation of any kind. There couldn't be. Slowly, inexorably, reverently, he lowered his tool to the task.

Bright red, the ink scored a line, and then another.

"I'm sorry, [Darlings](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&q=What%20does%20it%20mean%20to%20kill%20your%20darlings%3F&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcq5qQiaX9AhVtEFkFHVCkBV8Qzmd6BAg_EAU&biw=1920&bih=1031&dpr=1)." His voice was soft. He dragged the pen across the page, and with a another scratch it was done.